# About ideal floated measurement

Tags: measurement, grounding

In the book "Grounds for Grounding", p. 573, it give a figure:
[image]

And it states：

> In a perfectly balanced circuit (i.e., \$Z_{H} = Z_{L}\$ and \$Z_{HG}
> > = Z_{LG}\$), where \$Z_{HG}\$, and \$Z_{LG}\$ are also much larger than \$Z_{H}\$ and \$Z_{L}\$, high common-mode rejection is achieved
>   and no measurement errors are observed, that is, no differential
>   voltage offset exists across the input impedance, \$Z_{M}\$. In
>   practice, however, \$Z_{HG} \gg Z_{LG}\$, thus \$Z_{HG}\$ actually
>   amounts to an open circuit and the circuit in Figure 7.87 transforms
>   to that shown in Figure 7.88.

[image]

Similar statements also appear in HP's "AN123 Floating Measurements And Guarding".

My question is why \$Z_{HG} \gg Z_{LG} \$ in practice? Apparently we can use an instrument amplifier as the front end of a measurement apparatus. And make the difference between ZLG and ZHG as small as possible.

Comment: While the resistance to earth ground in both cases is quite high, the AC impedance of measurement ground to earth ground is typically low ( capacitance of transformer, ground plane to chassis etc )

Comment: Because it says this: "In practice, however, ZHG≫ZLG" then it must be talking about some specific piece of measuring apparatus because nobody sensible will design a sensitive differential amplifier with ZHG≫ZLG because that is asking for trouble. You design good diff amps with a balanced impedance to ground or, if balanced can't be achieved those impedances should remain massively high over the bandwidth of measurement. I also disagree with what the HP document says about ZHG≫ZLG.

Comment: @Andyaka, I noticed the book "Grounds for Grounding" may take HP's doc as a reference. But the HP's doc is a very ancient one, which the last revision date is "June 1970", if it's the situation at that days, that the the front of a measurement apparatus can't be made as balanced as today?

Comment: Nah I think it's plain wrong - telephony had been around nearly a hundred years in 1970 and cable companies and designers have been using balanced techniques for most of that time. It's just wrong what they say but, there is a (slight) chance that I'm misinterpreting what is said so I'm not leaving a formal answer.

Comment: Yes, the "grounds for grounding" is a book published more recently. So if we missed something?

Answer (score 0):

Clearly if Z<sub>H</sub>=Z<sub>L</sub> and Z<sub>HG</sub>=Z<sub>LG</sub> then the measurement will be immune to the common mode source.

In practice however, the construction of a typical instrument that has not been deliberately constructed to meet the above conditions will involve a nearly direction connection from the internal circuit ground reference to the external chassis or ground connection. This is the context of stating that typically Z<sub>HG</sub>>>Z<sub>LG</sub> since Z<sub>LG</sub> is nearly zero while Z<sub>HG</sub> is only due to weak parasitic coupling.

Edit: In the case where there has been a moderate attempt to isolate the internal ground from the external ground of the instrument, the simple fact that the internal ground structure is typically much larger than the positive side of the instrument, will introduce substantially higher parasitic coupling of the internal ground to the external ground creating an imbalance between Z<sub>HG</sub> and Z<sub>LG</sub>.

This is regularly demonstrated by freshman engineering students in the lab when they work on their first high voltage circuit, hoping to make a differential measurement with their scope only to garner a healthy shock or to let out the magic smoke. If the lab lights go out, it makes a fine teachable moment if the TA keeps his/her composure...

Comment: The picture does contain the words "floated measurement apparatus" and not "randomly put together supposedly diff amp by a freshman"!

Comment: @Andyaka  True! I did add some additional commentary in my answer.